# Crash on GeoServices

Tags: ios, swift

I am experiencing a crash only on **iOS 13**.

This is the stack trace:

```
Thread 52 name:
Thread 52 Crashed:
0   GeoServices                      0x00000001a16c3520 (null) (GeoServices)
1   GeoServices                      0x00000001a16ab110 addr_obj::venue::TemplateFactory::TemplateForStyleAndParams(addr_obj::venue::TemplateFactory::TemplateStyle, addr_obj::venue::VenueInfoFormatterParams const&) const (GeoServices)
2   GeoServices                      0x00000001a17717a0 addr_obj::venue::Formatter::fromPattern(addr_obj::venue::VenueInfoFormatterParams const&, addr_obj::venue::LabelContext) (GeoServices)
3   GeoServices                      0x00000001a1771ca8 addr_obj::venue::Formatter::Formatter(addr_obj::venue::VenueInfoFormatterParams const&, addr_obj::venue::LabelContext) (GeoServices)
4   GeoServices                      0x00000001a1773264 addr_obj::venue::Formatters::Formatters(addr_obj::venue::VenueInfoFormatterParams const&) (GeoServices)
5   GeoServices                      0x00000001a1777f08 addr_obj::VenueInfo::VenueInfo(addr_obj::venue::VenueInfoFormatterParams const&) (GeoServices)
6   GeoServices                      0x00000001a1700514 addr_obj::V1AddressObject::V1AddressObject(addr_obj::Localization const&, addr_obj::Fingerprints const&, addr_obj::AddressObjectProto const&, addr_obj::AddressObjectBase::AddressObjectVersion const&) (GeoServices)
7   GeoServices                      0x00000001a1704474 addr_obj::V2AddressObject::V2AddressObject(addr_obj::Localization const&, addr_obj::Fingerprints const&, addr_obj::AddressObjectProto const&, addr_obj::AddressObjectBase::AddressObjectVersion const&) (GeoServices)
8   GeoServices                      0x00000001a16d3f58 addr_obj::AddressObjectFactory::fromProto(addr_obj::AddressObjectProto const&, addr_obj::Localization const&) const (GeoServices)
9   GeoServices                      0x00000001a16d3248 addr_obj::AddressObjectFactory::parseBytes(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const (GeoServices)
10  GeoServices                      0x00000001a16d2048 addr_obj::AddressObjectFactory::fromBytes(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const (GeoServices)
11  GeoServices                      0x00000001a167ce08 -[GEOAddressObject initWithPlaceDataAddressObject:placeDataAddress:placeDataInfo:placeDataEntity:language:country:phoneticLocale:] (GeoServices)
12  GeoServices                      0x00000001a167cad8 +[GEOAddressObject addressObjectWithPlaceDataAddressObject:placeDataAddress:placeDataInfo:placeDataEntity:] (GeoServices)
13  GeoServices                      0x00000001a167c760 +[GEOAddressObject(PlaceDataExtras) addressObjectForPlaceData:] (GeoServices)
14  GeoServices                      0x00000001a167ee0c +[GEOAddress(PlaceDataExtras) geoAddressForPlaceData:] (GeoServices)
15  GeoServices                      0x00000001a167eacc -[_GEOPlaceDataItem addressDictionary] (GeoServices)
16  GeoServices                      0x00000001a167e6f0 -[GEOMapItemStorage(GEOMapItem) addressDictionary] (GeoServices)
17  CoreLocation                     0x000000019f556904 (null) (CoreLocation)
18  CoreLocation                     0x000000019f5573c4 (null) (CoreLocation)
19  CoreLocation                     0x000000019f54e178 (null) (CoreLocation)
20  libdispatch.dylib                0x000000019c0c9610 _dispatch_call_block_and_release (libdispatch.dylib)
21  libdispatch.dylib                0x000000019c0ca184 _dispatch_client_callout (libdispatch.dylib)
22  libdispatch.dylib                0x000000019c0a773c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$armv81 (libdispatch.dylib)
23  libdispatch.dylib                0x000000019c0a8154 _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$armv81 (libdispatch.dylib)
24  libdispatch.dylib                0x000000019c0b143c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread (libdispatch.dylib)
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x000000019c119fa4 _pthread_wqthread (libsystem_pthread.dylib)
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib          0x000000019c11cae0 start_wqthread (libsystem_pthread.dylib)
```

As you can see, the stack trace doesn't mention any code of the app but a system framework (GeoServices). 
This crash doesn't happen 100% of the times. I can't actually reproduce it but it is affecting some users and it has been reported in our crash reporter tool.

This is the code that we use to initialize CLLocationManager:

```
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
locationManager.distanceFilter = 5
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
locationManager.delegate = self
```

We don't do anything complex or weird. After that we just listen to the updates using the delegate methods.

While we were investigating this we found this thread mentioning the same issue:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/120110

Have you seen a similar crash or do you have any idea of what could be causing this?